# Logistic Equation Solution - Nurgaliev's law

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to solve dN/dt = bN^2 - dN

Please see the image of my full working.

[Working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM6i5.jpg)

I feel like I am messing up on the partial fractions part, because my final solution converges towards 500, which I know isn't right as it should increase exponentially as t increases. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your partial fractions is indeed incorrect. I recommend looking at this http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx

Comment: You can check your partial fraction decomposition by combining the two fractions and see if you get your original fraction.